Motley - motlier - motliest
I've just come across these inflective forms of the adjective motley, instead of the expected motleyer/motleyest.
Is this a pronunciation spelling, or a regular pattern like those for clayey and skyey? Unfortunately, I cannot retrieve a list of adjectives ending in -ey that is not a an alternative form of -y/-ie.
After all, we write honeyed, moneyed, hackneyed, etc.

Under "Forms", the (subscription-only) full Oxford English Dictionary has 1800s– motlier (comparative), motliest (superlative) They also have smiliest elsewhere. I see nothing unusual about those forms. Or holey, holier, holiest

It might sometimes be whimsical in the written form, but in spoken contexts, the holiest socks should normally be easily understood a referring to the socks with the most holes, rather than the most holy socks.

@FumbleFingers In clayey , skyey , or sprayey, t's clear that we have "-ey", unlike in motley. But what would be the adverbial -ly forms from them?

I've never seen motley used in the comparative or superlative, but motleyer wouldn't be 'expected' by me. Adjectives ending in -y normally have comparatives with an 'i' - happier, cheerier, bouncier etc.

I've never encountered comparative / superlative forms of clayey, and the full OED doesn't list them. I can't get to the actual text, but a Google snippet shows this from Chambers: clayiest Derivatives follow similar rules as those for inflections , ie a y following a consonant changes to an i before a following suffix (except -ing), whereas one following a vowel does not. As for comparatives / superlatives of skyey, sprayey, I'm not inclined to accept those as credible words, however you spell them.

@FumbleFingers We write honeyed, moneyed, hackneyed etc. though...

Except honey, money are nouns.  Motley isn't.

And regardless of spelling, what possible use are honeyer, monyier, hackneyer ??? But both honeyed and honied certainly exist, even if I can't be bothered to log in to the full OED to see if they give both spellings.

@Lambie Except honey, money are nouns. Motley isn't Are you implying there is some kinda rule dependng on PoS? If so, please answer the OP

...I suppose honeyedier and honeyedest might in theory be comprehensible in some unusual context, but I can't see them catching on.

How about that! Someone actually made it into print with honeyedest words (= the most metaphorically honeyed words). It seems anything's possible with English!

Gooier and gluier are the comparative forms of gooey and gluey.
In all the other examples I can find (like dopier) there are alternative spellings of the original adjective (e.g. dopey or dopy), so it's not clear whether these should be counted as genuine examples.

Yet, we still write honeyed, moneyed, hackneyed etc...

There just aren't that many adjectives that end in unstressed -ey and are commonly used in the comparative or superlative, at least in formal writing.
OneLook Dictionary Search turns up 49 adjectives ending in -ey; with false positives removed, I would give the resulting list as follows:
boney, cagey, choosey, clayey, cockney, curvey, dicey, dickey, dopey, flakey, flukey, gamey, gluey, gooey, goosey, grapey, hokey, holey, homey, mangey, matey, motley, mousey, multistorey, nosey, phoney, plaguey, pokey, pricey, ropey, scaley, scarey, slatey, spacey, stagey, tiddley, whiney, winey.
Taking a look at some of the more promising of these, there are sometimes hits on Google Books for forms such as "diceyer" (in quotation marks) or "priceyest", but I haven't seen any data that would make me conclude that there is an established rule worth worrying about.
I wouldn't really call -ier or -iest in this context a "pronunciation spelling", though, just a variant, as often exists even in the case of the positive endings -ey and -y.

Many of those ending in -ey would normally be spelled with simply -y. Bony, choosy, curvy, ... and the corresponding er/est would be normally spelled -ier, -iest. So there are even fewer than expected.
